# Random symbols in Source window instead of Russian characters in RStudio

Tags: encoding, rstudio

I have been googling and stackoverflowing (yes, that is the word now) on how to fix the problem with wrong encoding. However, I could not find the solution.

I am trying to load `.Rmd` file with **UTF-8** encoding which basically has Russian characters in it. They do not show properly. Instead, the code lines in the Source window look like so:

[image: the random symbols are Russian characters (1)]
[image: the random symbols are Russian characters (2)]

Initially, I created this `.Rmd` file long ago on my previous laptop. Now, I am using another one and I cannot spot the issue here.

I have already tried to use some `Sys.setlocale()` commands with no success whatsoever.

> I run **RStudio** on **Windows 10**.
>
> ---

#### Edited

This is the output of `readBin('raw[1].Rmd', raw(), 10000)`. Slice from 2075 to 2211:

```
[2075] 64 31 32 2c 20 71 68 35 20 3d 3d 20 22 d0 a0 d1 9a d0 a0 d0 88 d0 a0 
e2 80 93 d0 a0 d0 8e d0 a0 d1 99
[2109] d0 a0 d1 9b d0 a0 e2 84 a2 22 29 3b 20 64 31 32 6d 24 71 68 35 20 3d 
20 4e 55 4c 4c 0d 0a 64 31 35 6d
[2143] 20 3d 20 66 69 6c 74 65 72 28 64 31 35 2c 20 74 68 35 20 3d 3d 20 22 
d0 a0 d1 9a d0 a0 d0 88 d0 a0 e2
[2177] 80 93 d0 a0 d0 8e d0 a0 d1 99 d0 a0 d1 9b d0 a0 e2 84 a2 22 29 3b 20 
64 31 35 6d 24 74 68 35 20 3d 20
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't have very good support for UTF-8.  Likely your local encoding is something else.

RStudio normally reads files using the system encoding.  If that is wrong, you can use "File | Reopen with encoding..." to re-open the file using a different encoding.

Edited to add:

The first line of the sample output looks like UTF-8 encoding with some Cyrillic letters, but not Russian-language text.  I decode it as `"d12, qh5 == \"РњРЈР–РЎРљ"`.  Is that what RStudio gave you when you re-opened the file, declaring it as UTF-8?

Comment: Are you sure that file is UTF-8?

Comment: No, I am not sure. Is there a way to find it out? You know, the encoding it actually has.

Comment: Run `readBin("yourfile", raw(), 100)` and show us the result.  Maybe someone here will recognize it.  Russian in UTF-8 would look like ` [1] d0 9b d0 be d1 80 d0 b5 d0 bc 20 ...`

Comment: I don't think 100 chars was enough to get to the Russian bit.  That looks like a Windows file in ASCII, but lots of Russian encodings copy ASCII for Roman letters.  You'll need to read more until you get to the Russian part, which should show some bytes in the 80 to FF range.

Comment: Made it 500 chars.

Comment: Which bytes are 80 or more?

Comment: Yes, it is what RStudio gave me after I reopened the .Rmd with UTF-8 encoding. I actually have the next line: `d12, qh5 == "РњРЈР–РЎРљРћР™"` in the code.